# Unit Test Office Add-In with Mocha

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, office-js, office-addins

I try to write unit tests for an outlook 365 add-in.

So far I have mocked many classes with [ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito). However I facing a problem I currently can't easely evade. I get an `ReferenceError: Office is not defined` error executing my test. I tracked it down to the usage of Office Enums.

```
let item: MailItem;
// ...
let messageType = Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.ErrorMessage;
console.log('Won`t get here.');
item.AddNotification('Error404', { message: 'Element not found', type: messageType });
```

I mocked the `AddNotification` method, but I can't easely mock the Enum. I could create my own Enum and Write my on `AddNotification` method which get mocked, and internaly replace my own enum with the Office enum calling the original `AddNotification` method. But I don't like this aproach.

Including the `Office.debug.js` in the test using `--require` also didn't work.

I also tried to define the enums in the test class or the setup.js (which is `--required` by mocha).

```
export namespace Office {
    export module MailboxEnums {
        export enum ItemNotificationMessageType {
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is a progress indicator.
             */
            ProgressIndicator,
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is an informational message.
             */
            InformationalMessage,
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is an error message.
             */
            ErrorMessage
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to assing this enum to `global` so I can use it everywere.

```
export namespace Office {
    export module MailboxEnums {
        export enum ItemNotificationMessageType {
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is a progress indicator.
             */
            ProgressIndicator,
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is an informational message.
             */
            InformationalMessage,
            /**
             * The notificationMessage is an error message.
             */
            ErrorMessage
        }
    }
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
(global as any).Office = Office;
```